# Changing Paragon Portraits

Tags: diablo-iii

I just unlocked a new Paragon Portrait and I'm finding that I don't like the look all that much. I've tried right-clicking and looking through options, but  I haven't seen a way to change my selected Paragon Portrait. Can I switch back to a lower-level Paragon Portrait? If so, how?

Comment: no, but you can switch to a higher-level paragon portrait. Just get some levels :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*No, no way you can change to a lower-level...*

Oh wait! There is one now!

Version 2.2.0 added a **Cosmetics** screen, where you are free to "equip" any of Paragon portrait frames you've unlocked!

[image: Cosmetics]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Novarg for the info, didn't realise there are a update on it. After some dig through I added the portrait image that go beyond level 100 below. But unfortunately you are still unable to revert back to lower level portrait even with latest update.
[image]

[EDIT]

Currently you are unable to change to previous paragon portraits, following are current portrait image with paragon level:
[image: paragon portraits]

Comment: Paragon goes above level 100 now. Aren't there some more portraits for higher up in the line?

Comment: Currently no, [blue source](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/11985958483); I also see player with 200+ paragon level stuck with level 100 portrait.

Comment: @Josh.Macklin you are wrong, there are new portraits for Paragon levels 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700 and 800. [Source](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/13532431/patch-204-now-live-4-8-2014#general)

Comment: @Novarg, thanks for the info. Didn't realise there are a update on this, I edited the original post and include the new portrait for level 100 above.