# "Darkening of Tristram" paragon portraits on consoles

Tags: diablo-iii-console

The Diablo 20th anniversary event, "Darkening of Tristram" added two new paragon portrait frames that are not tied to one's paragon level. I earned one of them ("Classic Angel"), and it appears in my inventory, as seen in the screenshot below:

[image: Diablo Screenshot]

When I press the button to equip the item ('X' in this case), however, nothing seems to happen. My paragon portrait stays the same.

I've looked at the answer to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/163172/81131), but I can't find the cosmetics screen anywhere on the console interface. Is there any way to equip these special paragon portraits on the console editions of Diablo III?

Comment: In your Screenshot, you are Examining the item.  The UI says Press X (PS4) to Equip the item.  I play on Xbox, and the UI is the same (with different buttons).  The word `Equipped` will appear in gold/orange on the item which is currently equipped.

Comment: @blaughw I had the "examine" view open to show the details of the item in the screenshot. I pressed 'X' to equip, and nothing occurred. Sorry for the confusion -- I'll edit my wording.

Comment: Ok interesting.  I'm at paragon 195, so I'll probably hit 200 this weekend.  I understand this is supposed to result in a portrait, so hopefully I can reproduce this.  I'm sure I'll also be doing the Darkening event as well.

Comment: @blaughw I would be surprised if that allowed you to reproduce this. The paragon portraits that are tied to paragon levels do not show up as an item in your inventory; rather, they are auto-equipped. Just happened to me today when I reached paragon 40. However, the item I'm talking about is relatively easy to get if you feel so inclined -- collect "Cultist Pages" 1-7 from Temporal Cultists around the world, and you'll receive the item.

Comment: Seems to be a bug. Suggest to check back on this in a couple of weeks/months, if and when there will be a fix.

Comment: @DrFish Here's to hoping. Though given that the event is over after this month, I have my doubts as to whether it'll ever be fixed if it isn't fixed by the end of the month. Bummer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue. You will be able to change your paragon portrait when the 2017 update arrives (the one that will also bring the necromancer and the season and leaderboards ladder). See [this forum post](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/d3/topic/20752609978), made by a Blizzard community manager, that discusses the subject.

Comment: I've been searching around, and I can't seem to find any source that backs this claim up. I will mark as correct if you can provide a source.

Comment: https://us.battle.net/forums/en/d3/topic/20752609978

Comment: Thanks a ton, @blaughw. I'll update the answer with that link and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I have that same item. Seems you can't "equip" it or change your portrait in the console versions.

Comment: Glad to know I'm not the only one seeing this. I'm going to give it a week or so to see if anyone else comes up with anything. After that, I'll mark this as accepted.